# Easiest way to get a non-naive (aware) datetime of UTC now?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, utc

I was shocked to find that `datetime.utcnow()` returns a naive datetime object.  What is the easiest way to get a non-naive (aware) datetime object of "now"?  The only way I know to get that (`pytz.utc.localize(datetime.utcnow())`) seems to state the UTC aspect twice.  Isn't there a more direct way?

I know it is not a very complex piece of code and therefore acceptable.  But I'd like to understand why `utcnow()` doesn't return an aware object in the first place.  After all the TZ of the result is known, so why not put it in the object?

Comment: There was a downvote on my question.  I'd like to know why to improve it.  Please clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.utcnow) suggests using `datetime.now(timezone.utc)`.

E.g.

```py
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
# 2019-09-05 08:10:29.909459
print(datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc))
# 2019-09-05 08:10:29.910137+00:00
```